# How can I make applications opened by subprocess.Popen() stay open after my script exits?

Tags: python, windows

I want to launch Excel using `subprocess.Popen()` but my script doesn't work as expected.

The following simple script doesn't work in the way I want it to work. It looks like Excel is terminated immediately when the script ends. What do I need to do to keep it open?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE')
```

If I enter the same codes into the interactive shell, it works as expected and Excel stays open.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How long do you want Excel to remain open? `Popen` creates a new child process and returns immediately. Then your script terminates and thus its child process is killed. Do you want your script to pause at the Excel line until Excel terminates?

Comment: What I want to ultimately do is to start multiple applications (Excel, Word, and Chrome, for example) and keep them open until I manually close each application.

Comment: That's a very different question than the one you asked in the original title -- "work" doesn't generally imply "stay open after the parent process has exited", at least unless there's specific documentation that promises that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for answering my question. I was able to solve it myself. The reason Excel terminates was because I ran the script from VS Code. If I run the script from Command Prompt, Excel stays open.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

```
import os
os.system("start excel.exe")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

import subprocess

subprocess.run(r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE')

Stays Open Until Exit, Then you get this next line...

CompletedProcess(args='C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE', returncode=0)

If you want to do multiple, then multithreading is your answer.